# An already open DataReader for the ADO.NET Entity model in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, ado.net-entity-data-model, datareader

I'm using ADO.NET Entity model for data binding and other data manipulation for my ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor project.

I'm trying, in my model, to bind data like this in my `Controller`:

http://ideone.com/GvskaG

When I reach the line 26:

```
26. Sender = db.GetLoginByUserId(item.sender_id).FirstOrDefault(),
27. Receiver = db.GetLoginByUserId(item.recv_id).FirstOrDefault(),
```

I'm getting such an error:

**{"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."}**

Really, I don't understand how to close it manually, because ADO.NET Entity is too automatic, and I didn't define any opening are closing for the DataReader or connection.

I think, that it could be because of 15-th line:

```
15. var currentUserId = db.GetUserIdByLogin(Request.Cookies["user-name"].Value);
```

And the Entity model does open the connection/DataReader and removing them only after brace `}` symbol, when GC is collectiing the garbage.

It looks like I can make only one call in the single method, but if I want more calls from Entity model, how could it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps in a foreach loop at this point? That is the usual way of causing this - foreaching over the first reader while doing an n+1 (query per item) inside the loop. The usual fixes are  (one of):

- configure the query to eagerly fetch the nested data so that it is already available
- buffer the outer loop into a list/array, so that the reader is finished before the inner loop starts

Comment: I have changed the source of the `Controller` to the such code: http://ideone.com/jE6Ps1 and data is binding pretty fine without exceptions. Thanks for the advice, Marc, but I think the new code does look very ugly :( Is an Entity Model so whimsical?